# my HP Pavilion g6-1381ea core temperture is 70 at average

Tags: laptop, hp, overheating

my HP Pavilion g6-1381ea core temperature is 70 at average  and overheats. I don’t know what to do?

Comment: Please be more specific: my machine is currently running at 79°C and is *not* overheating (and I'm running at 65% processor capacity...)

Comment: For a system under load, 70 isn't that hot.  Modern CPUs typically have a maximum temperature of 95 C.

Comment: That's something you might be worried about. Everything above 60 is becoming dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

For a big server in an air-conditioned data-centre, anything above 60°C (140°F) is something to look at and above 70°C (158°F) something to worry about.

For a laptop, it depends on its use and environment:

- If it gets too warm to comfortably keep it on your lap, buy an external [passive cooler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laptop_cooler#Passive_coolers).
- If it's on a desk, just put a 2-3cm (1") thick book underneath the back side.
- If you're a heavy user ([video rendering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_renderer)/[conversion](https://libav.org/), [boinc](http://boinc.berkeley.edu/), ...) try to do the heavy stuff at night, turning the laptop on its side (not upside down) so it can use radiation *and* convection to get rid of excess heat.
- If you use the laptop primarily for gaming, you'll tax the GPU *and* CPU at the same time and an external [active cooler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laptop_cooler#Active_coolers) is a must for most laptops.

For all scenario's: vacuum all the vents regularly and you won't have any problems. I do this every month, but I smoke around my laptop.  Non-smokers, non-pet owners and other mysophobes could probably get away with doing this every 3-6 months or so.

**If the machine starts shutting down automatically, you've got a serious problem**: Download the service manual for your laptop, open it up, remove all dust from the inside, lightly vacuum it (put your vacuum cleaner on its nearly lowest setting) and then you're good for an additional 1-3 months before you have to vacuum it externally.